# Cannot set docker daemon insecure registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I cannot push to a remote registry I've configured:

Server:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2.7
```

Client:

```sh
cat --plain /etc/docker/daemon.json                                                                                                                                             
{
    "insecure-registries" : ["192.168.0.105:5000"]
}
sudo systemctl daemon-reload                                                                                                                                                    
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Tried this:

```sh
docker pull ubuntu
docker tag ubuntu 192.168.0.105:5000/ubuntu
docker push 192.168.0.105:5000/ubuntu

Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [192.168.0.105:5000/ubuntu]
Get https://192.168.0.105:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

So it seems the `daemon.json` insecure-registries entry is ignored. Indeed:

```sh
docker info | grep -i insecure -A 5                                                                                                                                             

 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

What could be the problem here?